# Grid.MVC - MVC 5 supports POST requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, http-post

I have a problem with calls to action with POST attribute exclusively from Grid.MVC tool.
I set up a column within the Grid.MVC tool, setting the property RenderValueAs follows:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
    // other lines...
    columns.Add().Encoded(false)
        .Sanitized(false)
        .RenderValueAs(item => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { item.ID }));
}).WithPaging(3).Sortable(true)
```

In my controller I have set the following code which refers to the Delete action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    // anything here
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The best practices tell you that the action method should support only POST requests, because deleting objects is not an idempotent operation. This because browsers and caches are free to make GET requests without the user’s explicit consent, and so I must be careful to avoid making changes as a consequence of GET requests.

But, when I try to apply this configuration I have the next error:

***Server Error in application '/'
Can not find the resource.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly***

But if I remove the [HttpPost] attribute the code works. Is this behavior correct?

Thanks

---

UPDATE:

Bayu, you have reason, now I explain the problem from another scenario: I had my View as follows:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        @*another columns*@
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.ID</td>
        @*another columns*@
        <td>@item.Name</td>
        <td>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Admin"))
            {
                @Html.Hidden("ID", item.ID)
                <input type="submit"
                        value="Delete row" />
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

That is, I used HTML tables, and therefore I could use an input to build a button that allows me to delete a row from the table.
Now, I want to use the tool Grid.View (because among other benefits allows me effortlessly filter columns), but I can not use an input for this purpose.
You have any idea how?

Comment: What you're doing with Html.ActionLink is actually a get request

Comment: I would recommend you to use something like jqgrid to help you accomplish your goal, hope this could help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594150/MVC-Basic-Site-Step-jqGrid-In

Answer (score 1):

Change  new { item.ID }) to  new {id = item.ID })